# Handling PHP require/include - control flow / interception

Tags: php

Is it possible to control the flow of all `include/require` statements in PHP; whether they're invoked by an autoloader or elsewhere?

I'm trying to intercept all inclusions and place my custom file before all others, with `require_once` so it won't get used by an autoloader or something/someone else.

`get_included_files/get_required_files` only list included files, but is there a workaround to place a file on top of that list, or just to control the flow of the inclusions, whether if there's an autoload or not?

Comment: `include` the file(s) you need before including the autoloader. Or write your own autoloader.

Comment: I'm aware of that, and that's not what I've asked.

Comment: What you have asked doesn't make much sense to me. If you work on a project, it's your decision what files you include and in which order. If you work on a library you cannot control what files are included before yours. So, what's the question?

Comment: My question was, if you read carefully: to control the inclusion of files before autoloader or any other means of including them.

Comment: And no, autoloader is not destined for that mission. Documentation states: _Many developers writing object-oriented applications create one PHP source file per class definition. One of the biggest annoyances is having to write a long list of needed includes at the beginning of each script (one for each class)._ ([source](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php))
 - I've never mentioned OOP/Namespacing, etc.

Comment: You said: *"I'm trying to intercept all inclusions and place my custom file before all others"* -- If you are working on a project then include the custom file before anything else. Case closed. If you are working on a library and I'm using the library in my project you cannot control when the files of the library are included. Most probably several files from my project or other libraries are already included when your code is loaded and executed. This completely defeats the purpose expressed in the quoted sentence.

Comment: With all due respect to your SO reputation, I believe my question was in spirit very PHP-general, and not project specific. If the thing you're saying is true, then it surely is a big shortage we lack in PHP, which may improve the workflow and maybe/probably, security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to control the flow of all `include`/`require` statements in PHP; whether they're invoked by an autoloader or elsewhere?

No, the PHP interpreter does not provide any way to hook into its mechanism of including files.

The only way to control what files are included is through an [autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) but it is invoked only when the code reaches a reference to an unknown class, interface or trait. It is not invoked when a file is `include`d/`require`d directly.

> I'm trying to intercept all inclusions and place my custom file before all others, with `require_once` so it won't get used by an autoloader or something/someone else.

As I tried to explain in my comments, when you write an application (CLI application or website) you control most file inclusions. You can just `include`/`require` the desired file before anything else and that's all. It won't be the first file in the output of [`get_included_files()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php) because it is not the first file loaded and executed. The main application file (the one that `include`s it) will always be the first one in list.

If you work on a library (i.e. a bunch of files that provide some useful functionality to be used in applications) then you cannot control the order of file inclusions. Several files of the application and of other libraries will be, most probably, already included when your code is included.

> `get_included_files`/`get_required_files` only list included files, but is there a workaround to place a file on top of that list, or just to control the flow of the inclusions, whether if there's an autoload or not?

The first file in the list returned by `get_included_files()` is always the main script; i.e. the one invoked by the web server or launched in execution using the CLI version of PHP. It includes the other files.

---

You can use the [`auto_prepend_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) `php.ini` setting to configure your PHP interpreter (both the CGI and CLI versions) to load a certain PHP file before any main script it loads.

It is still not what you want, it doesn't provide any hook into the inclusion mechanism. All it does is to [`require`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) the provided file on top of every main script it runs (as if every PHP script you request from the server starts with an invisible `require` statement).

Comment: I think `auto_prepend_file` is the closest to what OP is looking for,

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to intercept all inclusions and place my custom file before all others, with require_once so it won't get used by an autoloader or something/someone else.

While you mention "intercept" you don't seem to need to actually intercept more, you're wanting to push in front of them. Please clarify if this is a misunderstanding.

To *`place my custom file before all others`* you can use [auto_prepend_file](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) in `php.ini` (as stated by axiac).

you can do this in your account specific php.ini (usually called `user.ini` or similar) which is read before any PHP content files:

```
; Wordfence WAF Example
auto_prepend_file = '/home/accountname/public_html/wordfence-waf.php'
; END Wordfence WAF
```

The above means that when *any* PHP file is loaded on this account, that the `wordfence-waf.php` file is called and run *first*. This file has no idea what includes will run after it.

This is the closest PHP has to what I *think* you're trying to achieve. It may help if you clarify the wording of your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are no events so no listening.

Only way I could think of (apart from changing the source code of PHP in which case you should rethink the whole thing) is wrapping the include/require inside your custom function. Like this :

```
function custom_include($file){
    require_once("my_file.php");
    require_once($file);
}
```

Comment: I was asking generaly for any PHP thing. Sorry, this is not the solver.